# My program keeps on running the same if statement even though I update the variable it is checking for

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, nested, thread-sleep

I am trying to write a program for a timer, in which every time the timer progresses 1/5, the time it takes for the output to update is longer. I have done his using a sleep thread and 5 if statements, in which for every time the timerSeconds variable goes down 1/5, it slows down the output. However, my if statements don't seem to be working and I am getting the same delay every time. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

**Notes:** I have rewritten my if statements several times, and I wrote my delay based on a model of 5 intervals, in which the total delay should add up to 5 seconds.

I have also included a delay function which outputs the delay of the sleep thread, which is used purely to test if the system is accurate with its timing.

Thanks so much for any help!

**The issue:**

As you can see if you run my code, the delay is .4 seconds every time the code is run.

**How it should work:**

Example - the user inputs 5 seconds.

Second 5, the thread sleeps for .4 seconds.

Second 4, the thread sleeps for .6 seconds.

Second 3, the thread sleeps for 1 seconds.

Second 2, the thread sleeps for 1.2 seconds.

Second 1, the thread sleeps for 1.8 seconds.

So even though the outputs slow down, in total the timer ends after 5 seconds. Let me know if this is confusing!

**Here's my code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double time = 0; /*used for calculating delay
        bc sleep isn't always accurate so 
        essentially I want to double check if 
        the sleep function is delaying for the 
        amount of time I want it to */


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter time: ");

       double timerSeconds = input.nextDouble();

        for (int timeElapsed = (int)timerSeconds; timerSeconds > 0; timerSeconds--) {
          //timeElapsed is placeholder to avoid errors 
          
          long t1 = System.nanoTime(); //gets current System time 



/* 5 divides, the timer delay increases as the
 timerSeconds decreases, but timer should run for
  user input in the end*/

          if((timerSeconds >= (timerSeconds/5)*4) && !(timerSeconds <= (timerSeconds/5)*3)){

            try {
                Thread.sleep(400);
            } catch (Exception e) {//catches random exception to avoid crash 
                System.out.println(e);
            } 
           time = (System.nanoTime() - t1)/1000000; //calculates delay 
          }
          
          if((timerSeconds >= (timerSeconds/5)*3) && !(timerSeconds <= (timerSeconds/5)*2)&& !(timerSeconds >= (timerSeconds/5)*4)){

            

            try {
                Thread.sleep(600);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
           time = (System.nanoTime() - t1)/1000000;
          }
          
          if((timerSeconds >= (timerSeconds/5)*2) && !(timerSeconds <= (timerSeconds/5)*1)&& !(timerSeconds >= (timerSeconds/5)*3)){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
           time = (System.nanoTime() - t1)/1000000;
          }
          
          if((timerSeconds >= (timerSeconds/5)) && !(timerSeconds <= (timerSeconds/5))&& !(timerSeconds >= (timerSeconds/5)*2)){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1200);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
           time = (System.nanoTime() - t1)/1000000;
          }
          
          if((timerSeconds >0) && !(timerSeconds >= (timerSeconds/5))){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1800);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
           time = (System.nanoTime() - t1)/1000000;
          }

            
            System.out.println("\n" + timerSeconds + " Seconds Remaining");
             System.out.println("delay) "+ time); 
        }

        System.out.println("\n\n -----Timer is Up-----\n\n"); 




    }
}
```

Comment: If you need so many try-catches, just simplify it by throwing Exception.

Comment: "Let me know if this is confusing!" -- this is confusing.

Comment: @DaveNewton can you let me know which specific part I can clarify?

Comment: @ThomasJadallah Dunno, too confusing. I'd start by just examining your variables and logic conditions in your `if` statements; they're obviously wrong, but it's difficult to reason about the code. Wouldn't it be a lot easier to just update a counter on every timer expiry and use that counter to set the next delay?

Comment: @DaveNewton that's a good idea, I'll try that

Comment: @DaveNewton I got it working! I rewrote my if statements as there was an error. Essentially I created a new int called timerSecondsFifth and in my if statements I tested if it was less than the higher fifth and more than the lower fifth.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this, essentially by rewriting my if statements to test if the timerSeconds was lower than the previous fifth(which I stored in an int called timerSecondsFifth), and higher than the next fifth. Here's my code if anyone wants to take a look:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double time = 0; /*used for calculating delay
        bc sleep isn't always accurate so 
        essentially I want to double check if 
        the sleep function is delaying for the 
        amount of time I want it to */


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter time: ");

       double timerSeconds = input.nextDouble();

       double timerSecondsFifth = timerSeconds/5; 


        int timesRan = 0;

        for (int timeElapsed = (int)timerSeconds; timerSeconds > 0; timerSeconds--) {
          //timeElapsed is placeholder to avoid errors 
          
          long t1 = System.nanoTime(); //gets current System time 



/* 5 divides, the timer delay increases as the
 timerSeconds decreases, but timer should run for
  user input in the end*/

          if(timerSeconds > timerSecondsFifth*4 && timerSeconds <= timerSecondsFifth*6){

            try {
                Thread.sleep(400);
            } catch (Exception e) {//catches random exception to avoid crash 
                System.out.println(e);
            } 
           time = (System.nanoTime() - t1)/1000000; //calculates delay 

           
          }
          
          if(timerSeconds > timerSecondsFifth*3 && timerSeconds <= timerSecondsFifth*4){

            

            try {
                Thread.sleep(600);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
           time = (System.nanoTime() - t1)/1000000;
          }
          
          if(timerSeconds > timerSecondsFifth*2 && timerSeconds <= timerSecondsFifth*3){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
           time = (System.nanoTime() - t1)/1000000;
          }
          
          if(timerSeconds > timerSecondsFifth && timerSeconds <= timerSecondsFifth*2){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1200);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
           time = (System.nanoTime() - t1)/1000000;
          }
          
          if(timerSeconds <= timerSecondsFifth){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1800);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
           time = (System.nanoTime() - t1)/1000000;
          }

            
            System.out.println("\n" + timerSeconds + " Seconds Remaining");
             System.out.println("delay) "+ time); 
        }

        System.out.println("\n\n -----Timer is Up-----\n\n"); 




    }
}
```

Comment: Glad you worked it out. Still seems unnecessarily complex to me.